# Kendo grid time field parsing

Tags: templates, time, kendo-grid

I need to parse a time(time only) field in kendo.

search results following code,

```
'#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(dateCreated), 'MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt')#'
```

Since I could get only time from database, above formatting method wont work for this instance.

> 15:10:00

above is the time format im getting from DB side. How could i parse this time in following format

> 03:10 PM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the "t" [specifier](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/globalization/dateformatting#types-of-date-formats) in order to extract the time in the desired format:

```
kendo.toString(dateCreated, "t");
```

Here is a [Dojo example](http://dojo.telerik.com/eXAZi) to demonstrate the above in action.

Comment: for fille date time parsing, we can use `#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(DateTime, 'yyyy-MM-dd'),'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt') #`